# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in Graal-compiled JavaFX application

Tags: java, maven, javafx, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am working on a small OpenJFX project that can be compiled into a native app. Here's a sample of the relevant parts of the source code:

`Main.java`

```java
package app;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App.main(args);
    }

}
```

`App.java`

```java
package app;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("MainPanel"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
                App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

`pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>app.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                  <archive>
                    <manifest>
                      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                      <mainClass>app.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                  </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                  <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                  </descriptorRefs>
                  <archive>
                    <manifest>
                      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                      <mainClass>app.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                  </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.nativeimage</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-image-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>19.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>native-image</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <imageName>app</imageName>
                    <buildArgs>
                        --no-fallback
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <classifier>linux</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <classifier>mac</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>graal-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The project successfully compiles into two .jar files and a native binary (in this specific case, a Linux x86_64 Glibc ELF binary). The non-standalone .jar (that is later compiled by GraalVM) successfully executes using `java --module-path /usr/share/openjfx/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar target/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. However, the generated native binary, launched as `target/app` from the terminal, gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.App
    at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:304)
    at app.App.main(App.java:32)
    at app.Main.main(Main.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.App
    at com.oracle.svm.core.hub.ClassForNameSupport.forName(ClassForNameSupport.java:60)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(DynamicHub.java:1197)
    at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:292)
    ... 2 more
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong, is there some sort of silent compile error or missing parameters on the GraalVM side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue at play is that GraalVM cannot compile standalone binaries containing classes with reflection [unless told beforehand](https://www.graalvm.org/docs/reference-manual/native-image/#java-reflection-support). This should be possible to setup using `native-image-maven-plugin`, but I have instead switched to [Gluon Client](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-maven-plugin/), which means I have made the following additions to `pom.xml` after removing the no longer useful stuff:

```xml
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>gluon-releases</id>
        <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>app.App</mainClass>
                <reflectionList>
                    <list>javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader</list>
                    <list>app.SomeCustomClass</list>
                </reflectionList>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Notice that `app.SomeCustomClass` is an example of a class that returned a similar `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` error and `javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader` was added for the same reason.

Comment: BTW this also means that for now, unless you dare to manually handle all reflection, there is no Windows support: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1473